# Can I increase a c# character's value by addition?

Tags: c#

For instance, I want to do something like the following:

```
char output = 'A' + 1;
```

getting output of 'B'

However, simply trying what I have above gives a casting error.

Comment: What should 'Å' + 1 equal? B̊? Just realize you are working with the [UTF-16 encoding](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) of the [Unicode character set](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the binary `+` operator isn't defined on `char`, so you end up with implicit conversions to `int`. You can use a pre/post-increment operator:

```
char x = 'A';
x++;
```

... because the `++` operator *is* defined for `char`.

But otherwise, you need a cast:

```
char x = 'A';
x = (char) (x + 1);
```

Comment: I like the x++ example, that's a really concise way of doing it.

Comment: Why is the ++ operator defined, but the + operator not?

Comment: @TomasZubiri: That's just the way it is, to be honest... presumably it was viewed as being useful this way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast the operation yourself, like so

```
char output = (char)('A' + 1);
```

Comment: No need for the cast of `1` to `char`... it will be implicitly converted back to `int` anyway.

Comment: No, check the documentation, you can implicitly convert char to int but not the other way around: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx - you *do*, in fact, need to do the explicit cast.

Comment: Hmm, listen to JonSkeet, or this EJoshuaS guy.. Try this @EJoshuaS: `int v = (char)1;`, compiles just fine. I think that's Jon's point, casting it to `char` does nothing because you cannot add `char`'s together, so even though you write `'A' + (char)1` it's casting it back to int and adding  like this `(int)'A' + (int)((char)1)` anyways.

Comment: int var = (char)1 *should* work because there's an implicit conversion from char to int. however, "char v = 1" would *not* compile because there's no implicit conversion from int to char.

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated, yes, it's absolutely possible. The other answers gave examples so I won't repeat them. However, I'd like to give the caveat here: if all you do is "blindly" add a number to the character, you might get unexpected results. For example, Z + 1 = '['. If that's the result you expect, that's great - otherwise you have to handle that. There's also the possibility that adding to a char will result in an unprintable character (e.g. ~ + 1 = 'DEL', which isn't printable, and 'DEL' + 1 isn't "standard" ASCII anymore).

You have to consider the following cases: what's the result of adding 1 to Z, z, or 9? Can you get non-letter inputs or outputs - e.g. would { + 1 (result: '|') be valid? What about Z + 1 = '['? What do you do at ASCII 127 (the last valid ASCII character)? What about non-printable characters?

If, for example, you're expecting the inputs to be only letters and numbers and you want the results to "wrap around" at the end of the valid range (e.g. Z + 1 = A, z + 1 = a, 9 + 1 = 0) you can do something like the following:

```
char bChar = 'A'; // Or whatever you want, obviously
switch (bChar)
        {
            case 'z':
                bChar = 'a';
                break;
            case 'Z':
                bChar = 'A';
                break;
            case '9':
                bChar = '0';
                break;
            default:
                bChar++;
                break;
        }
```

The main thing is to make a decision about what should happen with these "edge cases" and make sure you handle them properly.

Comment: ASCII doesn't have a role in the character and string data types of modern programming languages. Your points do apply to Unicode codepoints, though, and even more to the disjoint ranges of UTF-16 code units (`char`).

Comment: @TomBlodget True, ASCII's dying a slow, painful death; there's some overlap though so a lot of the things I describe apply to both and you have the same issue regardless of which character set you're using. You're correct about UTF-16 in particular. Either way, the point being while it's technically "legal" to shift a character by adding to it you usually have to be a little more sophisticated than that or you risk being unpleasantly surprised about what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int ASCIINumber = (int)'A'; //101 A
char charResult = Convert.ToChar(ASCIINumber + 1);  //102 or B
```